# Existence of a non-constant continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X , d)$ be a connected metric space and let $(Y , d)$ be a discrete metric space. Then I know that every continuous function from $(X , d)$ to $(Y , d)$ is a constant function.

So is it true that there always exist a non-constant function from a connected metric space $(X , d)$ to a non-discrete metric space $(Y ,d)$. I am struggling to prove it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Let $X$ be the real line with the usual metric and $Y=\{0,\frac 1 2, \frac 1  3,...\}$ with the usual metric. If $f$ is a non-constant continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ then IVP property is violated since $Y$ is countable. Note that $0$ is not an isolated point of $Y$ so the $Y$ is not discrete.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Thanks for editing.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Is there any characterization of the metric space (Y , d) such that existence of a non-constant continuous function  from a connected metric space (X , d) to (Y , d) is guaranteed. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Let $X$ be any connected metric space (for example, $[0,1]$) and $Y$ any totally disconnected metric space; that is, one in which every connected component is a single point (for example, $\mathbb{Q}$).  Then $C(X\to Y)$ contains no non-constant functions.  For: if $f\in C(X\to Y)$, then $\mathrm{rng}{(f)}$ is connected, and so contained in a connected component of $Y$, which must be a singleton.